# How Do I Use A Custom Mobile Theme?

Tags: themes, theme-options, mobile

I have a self hosted blog and I want it to be mobile compliant. I know there is a free plugin the serves this purpose. However, I want to use a simple mobile theme I like (say from Theme Forest). How do i go about it? Is it as straight forward as uploading a normal theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the theme in question,

- Some themes have a desktop and mobile versions built in.
- Some themes are made to fit the screen size (responsive).
- Some themes (for mobile) come as a plugin which activates it self
  when the user access the site from a mobile device.

So In the either way its a matter of activating and configuring the theme or plugin.